# HTML5 accept attribute for image uploader - get value through POST

Tags: php, html, file-upload, image-uploading

I've been trying to find out how to utilise the HTML5 `file` type with the `accept` attribute but have been struggling to find any details about the best way to use it.

At present all I can understand is that it gets the name of the file. How do I actually get the data? How do I store it on the server?

```
<input type="file" id="feature" name="feature" accept="image/*">
```

This is the PHP after the post submission:

```
$pic = $_POST["feature"];
echo $pic; // just outputs the filename
```

Comment: use move_upload_file() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST value of a file input will only ever show the filename. The file itself is uploaded to a temp file. It's up to you to move it to where you want it to be with `move_uploaded_file()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

From the manual:

```
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["feature"]["tmp_name"]; //The temporary file
    $name = $_FILES["feature"]["name"]; // It's name
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name"); //Put it there
```

When working with files, use `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

**IMPORTANT**

None of this will work however if you do not add the enctype attribute to your upload form.

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried implementing this but I get an undefined index for both occurrences of [feature] - this is the name of the input field so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck with your app. Please hit the checkmark by my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["feature"]["tmp_name"],"yourUploadFolder/" . $_FILES["feature"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. However i get undefined index for "feature". What should be there?

Comment: @Francesca That's cus you're not adding the enctype attribute to your form. See my answer.